# comparing two tab seperated files for multiple column and combine matches

Tags: python, perl, command

I need to compare two files for first two columns and select the matched ones with additional information of second file like;

input1:

```
0   1
2   4
5   6
```

input2:

```
2   4  xyz
5   4  asv
0   1  qwe
```

output is

```
2   4  xyz
0   1  qwe
```

i tried this at python but does not work properly; like if there are more 1 at first column it cannot give proper output

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

f1 = 'file1.txt'
f2 = 'file2.txt'

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    f1 = sys.argv[1]
    f2 = sys.argv[2]

with open(f1) as file_1, open('out.txt', 'w') as of:
    for l1 in file_1:
        col_of_f1 = int(l1.split()[0])
        with open(f2) as file_2:
            for l2 in file_2:
                col_of_f2 = l2.split()
                if len(col_of_f2) < 1:
                    break
                col_of_f2 = int(col_of_f2[0])
                if col_of_f1 == col_of_f2:
                    of.write(l2)
                    break
```

Comment: And ... What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: why `python` AND `perl` tag hough? can you show us some code so we can help you?

Comment: for python i tried this but doesnot work properly  

f1 = 'file1.txt'
f2 = 'file2.txt'

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    f1 = sys.argv[1]
    f2 = sys.argv[2]
with open(f1) as file_1, open('out.txt', 'w') as of:
    for l1 in file_1:
        col_of_f1 = int(l1.split()[0])
        with open(f2) as file_2:
            for l2 in file_2:
                col_of_f2 = l2.split()
                if len(col_of_f2) < 1:
                    break
                col_of_f2 = int(col_of_f2[0])
                if col_of_f1 == col_of_f2:
                    of.write(l2)
                    break

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this code after initializing f1 and f2

```
s1=open(f1,'r').read().split('\n')
s2=open(f2,'r').readlines()
of=open('out.txt','w')
ans=''
for i in s1:
    for j in s2:
         if i in j:
             ans+=j+'\n'
of.write(ans)
of.close()
```

Comment: hi , i tried but it just copied first file directly do not eliminate or select common lines

Comment: this code worked with the input and output you gave in the question. just take try giving the inputs you gave in the question